# Как в sql запросе добавить новое поле со значенем из других полей пропуская NULL

Tags: sql, база-данных, psql

[image: Таблица, выделенный жирным шрифтом]

Есть такая вот таблица, нужно вывести список всеx строк, дополнительно к этому создать в результирующем наборе поле с новым названием ‘three’.
Поле должно заполняться по следующему правилу:

1. Если one содержит значение отличное от NULL, то это значение должно
   отображаться в поле ‘three’
2. Если one содержит значение NULL, а поле two содержит значение отличное от
   NULL, в поле ‘three’ должно отображаться значение поля two
3. Если оба поля one и two содержат NULL значения, в поле ‘three’
   должно выводиться 'N/A'.
   Например при выводе этой таблице должен добавиться еще один столбец 'three' со значениями для id 1 - 2,id 2 - 3 и для id 3 -  значение 4.

Comment: это не учебное задание, это очень упрощенное представление моей главной таблицы. У меня не получается при выводе добавить еще один столбец и написать ему условие. Поэтому я упростил таблицу и нуждаюсь в помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `COALESCE` для того, чтобы выбрать первое не NULL значение из нескольких:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(one, two, 0) AS three
from test
```

Тут, если и `one`, `two` будут `NULL` - то в результате получим `0`.
Сделать как вы хотите и возвращать числа в одном случае и строку в другом нельзя, тип колонки фиксированный.

Можно разве что изменить тип колонки `three` и сделать его текстовым, и тогда придется конвертировать значения из `one` и `two` и возвращать их строковое представление вот так:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(one::text, two::text, 'N/A') AS three
FROM test
```